# Questions about Angular $q defer object

Tags: angularjs

I'm new with Angular and I've been playing around with it for almost 2 weeks now.

I had an implementation issue that I managed to solve. The overview of the problem is that I had a `main.html` that displayed all user information but didn't get updated by the service function `this.list` when I tried to add new information using service `this.addNewUser`. Below is the working version of the code and the version that didn't work.

The reason why I posted here even though I solved my own problem is that I'm curious to find out **why**. I want to understand what the difference is between the two examples of the *defer object*.  The second example does not work but the first example is working perfectly fine.

Does the difference have something to do with the defer object where I can only declare it inside the function?  Perhaps I can't declare it globally?

I am hoping someone can explain why the first example works but the second example does not.

---

**#1 Example**

```
//Add single user
this.addNewUser = function(username,email){

    **var deferred_2 = $q.defer(); //current active object for asyn ajax call**

    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/app/add.php',
        params: {
            "name":username,
            "email":email,
        },
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        deferred_2.resolve('Success');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log('Data :: ' + data);
        console.log('Status :: ' + status);
        console.log('Config :: ' + config);

    });

    return deferred_2.promise; //Promise object is the results

}
```

**#2 Example**

```
  var deferred_2 = $q.defer(); //current active object for asyn ajax call

//Add single user
this.addNewUser = function(username,email){

    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/app/add.php',
        params: {
            "name":username,
            "email":email,
        },
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        deferred_2.resolve('Success');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log('Data :: ' + data);
        console.log('Status :: ' + status);
        console.log('Config :: ' + config);

    });

    return deferred_2.promise; //Promise object is the results

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I call another function which is shown below, it's not updating the `main.html` with the new data which just inserted by using the function from the service `this.addNewUser`.

```
//List all user
this.list = function(){

    console.log('About to start');

    //Get Data
    $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/app/get.php',
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            deferred_2.resolve(data);

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            deferred_2.reject("Something bad here");

        });

        return deferred_2.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Snooper - I have edited your question to focus on the conceptual aspect of _why_ the second example wasn't working.  Conceptual programming questions are on-topic and appropriate for Programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Services in AngularJS are singletons which means the global `deferred_2` will have already been resolved (or rejected) by your first function.

From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

> The purpose of the promise object is to allow for interested parties
>   to get access to the result of the deferred task when it completes.

Because the deferred task has already been completed, subsequent calls to mark it as resolved or rejected won't trigger the any callbacks you have attached to the second promise. I don't think there's any reason to share deferrends between functions - if you want the list to update after you've added a new user, I suggest you look at Angular's `$emit`, `$broadcast` and `$on` methods for eventing on the `$scope` object :)